# Vuex mapActions: mapper parameter must be either an Array or an Object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When I'm trying to use the "getProducts" method through mapActions i am getting the "this.getProducts" is not a function.

Basically i get the actions from my product.js. So i don't know really why the error is existing.

I hope u can help me to handle with it. :)

My component **ProductList.vue**:

```
<script>
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard.vue";
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  components: {
    ProductCard
  },
  computed: {
    //state.modulname.state.js(products state)
    ...mapState("product" ["products"])
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getProducts();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("product"["getProducts"])  
  }
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

My **product.js** File:

```
import store from "../../store/store";
import Product from "../../apis/Product";

const state = {
 product: null,
 products: [],
};

const mutations = {
 SET_PRODUCT(state, product) {
 state.product = product;
},

 SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
  state.products = products;
 },
};

const actions = {
 getProduct({ commit }, productId) {
  Product.show(productId).then((response) => {
   commit("SET_PRODUCT", response.data);
  });
 },
 getProducts({ commit }) {
  Product.all().then((response) => {
   commit("SET_PRODUCTS", response.data);
  });
 },
 };

 const getters = {
 
 getProductID() {
  return (id) => state.products.filter((product) => product.id === id);
 },
};

 export default {
  namespaced: true, 
  store,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
};
```

Comment: Try `...mapActions("product", ["getProducts"])`. Same goes for `mapState`. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...mapActions([
  'product/getProducts'
])
```